# How to calculate hamming distance between two binaries on elasticsearch

Tags: algorithm, elasticsearch, binary

I want to save the binaries in elasticsearch and then return the resulted query based on score of similarity (based on hamming distance). So i can retrieve the closest ones (which will have more score).

Examples:

0000111100000000000000001
0000111100000000000000000

(hamming distance is 1, which is near, high score)

0000111100001110000000001
0111110100000001111100000

(hamming distance is 13, which is far, low score)

I want to bring the closest ones, and if near enought detect that they are almost the same.

Comment: How exactly are those "binaries" represented ? You can take the bitwise XOR and count the ones.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the FENSHSES (Fast Exact Neighbor
Search in Hamming Space on Elasticsearch) method proposed by this recent paper:

Mu, C, Zhao, J., Yang, G., Yang, B. and Yan, Z., 2019, October. Fast and Exact Nearest Neighbor Search in Hamming Space on Full-Text Search Engines. In International Conference on Similarity Search and Applications (pp. 49-56). Springer, Cham.

It seems to be the state-of-the-art one to conduct nearest neighbor search in Hamming space on Elasticsearch.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24943527)

Comment: @stats0007 it is not a link but a citation on a published conference paper, but I would add more contents into the answer.